# Set Nested serializer as optional in parent serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hi I have two serializers IndividualResponseSerializer the parent serializer and DependantResponseSerializer the nested serializer.

I would like to make the nested serializer optional incase the the parent model object has no child objects of dependants. I tried using allow_null when declaring the nested serializer but it did not work

Serializers.py

```
class DependantResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dependant
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'other_names',
            'gender',
            'date_of_birth',
            'relationship',
            'created_by',
            'modified_by',
            'id'
        )


class IndividualResponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dependants = DependantResponseSerializer(allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'other_names',
            'gender',
            'date_of_birth',
            'blood_group',
            'residential_address',
            'workplace_address',
            'additional_telephone_no',
            'NIN',
            'next_of_kin_name',
            'next_of_kin_telephone',
            'next_of_kin_email',
            'product',
            'dependants',
            'verified',
            'created_by',
            'modified_by',
            'id'
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had forgotten to set the many option when declaring the nested serializer, allow_null is not required as it was necessary in older versions of DRF

```
dependants = DependantResponseSerializer(many=True)
```